# Cloudflare SSL with Godaddy domain

Tags: https, godaddy, cloudflare

I transferred my site's nameservers to cloudflare in order to get SSL, but it isn't working. At first I got the error: 526, but then I changed the setting from Full SSL (strict) to just Full SSL. Once I did that though, when I changed the URL to HTTPS while googling it, it just gives the default message for godaddy that is usually shown when the site isn't there ("future home of something quite cool"). It gave the same message when I changed the SSL setting to flexible. I rechecked my settings, cloudflare says I have an active certificate, and HSTS is on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say that you have transferred your sites hosting to cloudflare. Cloudflare is a CDN, DNS, DDoS protection & web security provider, they do not provide hosting as a service. Also you need to upload your own SSL certificate to cloudflare if you want to be able to use SSL through cloudflare. Cloudflare will work as a reverse proxy to your actual host (Godaddy in this case).

Comment: Sorry, I'm sort of new at this. Why does it say "Active certificate" under crypto if I don't have a certificate? I assumed that they gave me one when I saw that

Comment: If you are only using cloudflare as a CDN you can enable SSL which will then serve your CDN content from a SSL cloudflare domain. This is why it is allowing you to enable SSL without uploading a certificate. If you scroll down to "Certificates" you can upload your own. The free plan does not allow for custom certificates. I have added an answer to this equation which I hope will answer some of your questions.

Comment: I know this is late but I changed from full to flexible and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudflare is not a webhost, they are a CDN, DNS, DDoS protection, Web Security Provider.

If you are using Cloudflare you are still required to have a separate web host for your website. Cloudflare will act as a middle man in between your web server and your users, this way your users would connect to cloudflare and Cloudflare will fetch the content from your server and then relay this back to the end user.

This allows Cloudflare to mitigate a multitude of DDoS attacked as well as filter out any bad requests so that they do not reach your web server. Cloudflare will also cache your static files so that they can be served via the Cloudflare CDN.

Additionally using the Cloudflare DNS service will allow your users to resolve the Cloudflare edge servers IP addresses faster since DNS queries will be sent to the Cloudflare server closest to the user.

Since SSL certificates are only valid for the domains they were created for, in order to get SSL working with Cloudflare you will have to purchase an SSL certificate for your domain name separately and then upload this certificate inside the Cloudflare control panel for your site. Cloudflare will then use this certificate when serving content for your site.

If you have altered or removed the content from your GoDaddy hosting this might be the reason why you are seeing the default GoDaddy page. Since that is the response Cloudflare is seeing while trying to access your real content.